# Concatenate multiple values in same row into a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where I want to do multi-label classification. One of the ways which was suggested to me was to calculate the probability vector. Here's an example of my DF with what would represent training data.

```
    id  ABC DEF GHI
1   0   0   0   1
2   1   0   1   0
3   2   1   0   0
4   3   0   1   1
5   4   0   0   0
6   5   0   1   1
7   6   1   1   1
8   7   1   0   1
9   8   1   1   0
```

And I would like to concatenate columns ABC, DEF, GHI into a new column. I will also have to do this with more than 3 columns, so I want to do relatively cleanly using a column list or something similar:

```
col_list = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']
```

The result I am looking for would be something like:

```
    id  ABC DEF GHI Conc
1   0   0   0   1   [0,0,1]
2   1   0   1   0   [0,1,0]
3   2   1   0   0   [1,0,0]
4   3   0   1   1   [0,1,1]
5   4   0   0   0   [0,0,0]
6   5   0   1   1   [0,1,1]
7   6   1   1   1   [1,1,1]
8   7   1   0   1   [1,0,1]
9   8   1   1   0   [1,1,0]
```

Comment: with [ ] character ???

Comment: Not sure, I guess if it was just a string, it would be okay, I could convert to a list after...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'agg' with function 'list':

```
df[cols].agg(list,axis=1)                                                                                            

1    [0, 0, 1]
2    [0, 1, 0]
3    [1, 0, 0]
4    [0, 1, 1]
5    [0, 0, 0]
6    [0, 1, 1]
7    [1, 1, 1]
8    [1, 0, 1]
9    [1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
col_list = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']
df['agg_lst']=df.apply(lambda x: list(x[col] for col in col_list), axis=1)
```

Comment: Any chance you can modify to include the reference to `col_list`? I might have a bunch of columns and I would like to avoid typing them all out every time.

Comment: I tweaked my answer including ```col_list```